# Tor won't start, no hostname

Tags: configuration

I installed Tor and a webserver on a box running Centos 6, the webserver is working fine but Tor is not starting correctly or creating the hostname file. When I try to start it, it says this:
`[root@EU1 ~]# /etc/init.d/tor restart
Stopping tor:                                              [FAILED]
Raising maximum number of filedescriptors (ulimit -n) to 16384.
Starting tor:                                              [  OK  ]
[root@EU1 ~]# ulimit -n
65000
[root@EU1 ~]#`

Comment: Tor seens to be starting correctly from that. And Tor doesn't create a hostname, you should create one manually and declare it in torrc file. Do you want help about how to create and configure a hostname in Tor?

Comment: Yes please, Linostar, I read in the forum tutorial I was going off of that it wrote it automatically to a file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create and configure a hidden service hostname?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6125/how-do-i-create-and-configure-a-hidden-service-hostname)